# Missing mfc140u.dll when trying to run windows application using Wine in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, wine

I want to run a c++ application written in vs2017 in Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed Wine version 3.0.3 as well as Winetricks version 20140817. When trying to run the application using 'wine app_name.exe' command, i get an error saying

```
002e:err:module:import_dll Library mfc140u.dll (which is needed by L"path_to_my_application_library") not found
```

I tried to install mfc140u via Winetrichs GUI using 'Install a Windows DLL or component' option but it seems not to be listed anywhere on the list of the available packages. Does anyone know how to make it available?

Comment: How did you go?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the most up-to-date version of Wine (currently Wine 4). You can check by running:

`wine --version`

If you need to upgrade Wine, check out the instructions [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/).

That dll is a part of Visual C++ redistributable. You'll need to install it so the application will work. [Instructions are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852407/wine-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015/852414#852414).

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Wine, so there could be additional steps, but in the interest of helping:

I believe you need the appropriate version of the [VC++ redistributable (Visual Studio C++ runtime)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). You need to install the version that the application you try to run was compiled with. Just start with the latest one and install and then install older versions if need be. [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1e58044d-8917-4a30-bee4-408593d66fc4/how-to-solve-mfc140udll-is-missing-error-in-mfc-vc?forum=vcgeneral).

Answer (score -1):

Download
vc_redist.x64.exe
from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

from console run
wine uninstaller

uninstall any existing runtime version, then select "install" and browse for the vc_redist.x64.exe file, accept. Execute your Windows appplication